# Use slick carousel with zepto

Tags: carousel, zepto

Is there a way for slick carousel to work with zepto.js?
I want to use zepto for because this is a mobile app and need a smaller library to load than jquery.

Comment: https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/653